# How can I write an if condition to check the address' state?

Tags: apex, address

I've written this condition in a class:

```
if (lead.State == 'New York' || lead.State == 'NY') {
    lead.Rebate__c = lead.Total_Savings__c * 0.60;
} else {
    lead.Rebate__c = 0;
}
```

But this doesn't get triggered all the time, and I suspect it's because `lead.State` is kinda integrated into an `Address` field. How can I write the condition to look at the state alone?

**Update**

It's not the picklist so `StateCode` doesn't work.

**Update 2**

I need to query the lead's `Address` object, which the docs tell me to do like so:

```
Adddress a = lead.Address;
String state = a.getState();
```

But that just returns an error.

**Update 3**

The docs do tell me I can access it with `lead.State` but it just returns `null` even when the state of the lead is `NY`. How do I access the state string inside the address?

Comment: Where is this code being used? Looks ok for me. You might want to decide to use a workflow for this.

Comment: @CD-RUM Why don't you set `Rebate__c` as a formula field?

Comment: Why should I have to break out of my class just for this? This is part of a much bigger class, and the code belongs in it.

Comment: @CD-RUM Well if that's the only functionality of that field, it's much better to move it to a formula field. (imo)

Comment: lead.State is the field you want to use. Is that field being filled in by the user manually, or is something else populating it? Have you enabled state/country picklists? The Address.getState() method should work too, what is the error it is giving you?